# FirebaseAuth: getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@8a06e29

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am building a social media app using Flutterfire in its most updated version.  I set up firebase authentication to register and login a user. Now when I tested this on the simulator, a successful login goes straight to the homepage.  However on the emulator, after pressing login, I get this message:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14785): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14785): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14785): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14785): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14785): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(14785): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@8a06e29
```

The first thing I did was check my build.gradle codes.  Here is what I have at the project level:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is what I have in the build.gradle at the app level of the android section:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.robin.rootsfolio_2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        //multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
}
```

And finally, here is the functionality I gave the register button:

```
class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  Register({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  registerUser() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
        .then((signedUser) {
      userCollection.doc(signedUser.user.uid).set({
        'username': usernameController.text,
        'password': passwordController.text,
        'email': emailController.text,
        'uid': signedUser.user.uid,
        'profilePic':
            'https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQGf401qFr-mKA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0?e=1602720000&v=beta&t=VUIqS71Qen3UQf64ddCYMq4A4YOkEt21MnTTPaASKP4'
      });
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

And the login button:

```
InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                try {
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: emailController.text,
                      password: passwordController.text);
                } catch (err) {
                  SnackBar snackBar =
                      SnackBar(content: Text('Email or password is incorrect'));
                  Scaffold.of(context);
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                height: 50.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Login',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.white, 
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                    )
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

I don't understand why this works fine for IOS and not Android.  Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has its own path to integrate Firebase libraries.  You don't need to make changes to build.gradle to add Firebase libraries.  So, it's unclear to me why you added these lines:

```
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
```

If you want to add Analytics to your app, follow the [instructions for Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#add-flutterfire-plugins), not Android.  You need to add the package as a dependency in pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # Check that you have this dependency (added in the previous step)
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9

  # Add the dependency for the FlutterFire plugin for Google Analytics
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
```